# How do I toggle cell output in JupyterLab Version 3.4.4?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In older versions I could press Esc+o and this still works in "classic notebook", but does not carry over to modern mode.

How do I get this behavior in the rest of the application?

The "toggle cell output collapsed" option is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a blue bar next to the cell output. When you click it will hide the cell output.

There is also a command "Collapse All Outputs" which you can access from the [Command Palette](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/commands.html). You can assign this command to a new shortcut in Settings Editor.